# Black Jack Probability Theoretical vs Simulation

Tags: probability, statistics

I am comparing the probability of winning blackjack by theoretically calculating it with probability equations and running realistic simulations in matlab.

If I assume 3 decks are used, dealer sits at 18, and only the player's cards are considered in calculations, I calculate every possible combination of getting 19, 20, and 21 and run the probability equation for it. Example: 10 and ace would get you (16*4)/(factorial(156)/(factorial(2)*factorial(156-2))) = 0.0476.  After all of the probabilities are added, the total probability of getting 19, 20, or 21 is 0.6552.

Then I create a simulation where 3 decks are shuffled and cards are drawn from the top.  If the cards drawn do not equal to 19,20,or 21 more cards are drawn.  After running 1000s of these, the probability of winning I get is 0.4625.

Why might these probabilities be so different?  I know I am short cutting a lot of how the game is played, but I feel like I am modeling them the same way.  Is it so much less in real life because the simulation isn't considering every possible little way of winning even though a lot of simulations are run?

Comment: I think you'll have to add more detail about what you do. I don't understand what you mean by "$10$ and ace would get you", and I don't understand where $16\cdot4$ comes from. The answer to your question "Why might theses probabilities be so different?" could be either "because there's an error in your calculations", "because there's an error in your simulation code" or "because you've made some simplifying assumptions in the calculation", and we have no way of knowing which it is without knowing exactly what you did.

Comment: In each deck, there are 10s, jacks, queens, and kings which equate to a value of 10 for blackjack and an ace high equates to 11 -> giving you a value of 21.  So in each deck there are 16 opportunities to get a 10 and 4 opportunities to get an ace.  I should've multiplied each of these by 3 (for the three decks) above, but I did that in my code so that's not the issue.

Comment: Since apparently you have code both for the calculation and for the simulation, I'd suggest that you show it to us. Without that, there's really not much we can say, except that there must be an error in one of them. What you write in the last paragraph of the question isn't the explanation. If the winning probability is $0.6552$, you should be getting something much closer than $0.4625$ if you run thousands of simulations.

Comment: One way of showing the code would be to post it on [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/).